# Swift: masks as type properties

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

my problem. I'm working with a NSEvent, which happens to have a var **modifierFlags** of type **NSEventModifierFlags**.

I want to check whether the user had a modifier key pressed (Command), so basically I want to check if **CommandKeyMask** is on.

What's the best/right way to do this in Swift ?

Comment: use bitwise operators, maybe...?

Comment: Best way, not the "C" way or "get it to work" way

Comment: the _Swift_ fully supports all bitwise operators, that is not the _C-way_ only. have you even read the docs about _Swift_? you can read more about the operators here, the very first paragraph is just about the bitwise operators. unskippable. educational. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-XID_28

Comment: Dude, please, don't go all high and mighty on me. And if you use full stops, capitalise first letters. I'm curious whether there is a support for this, built into the language syntax. The syntax you mention is known to me, but in Swift it seems as a less succinct solution than it used to be in C/ObjectiveC. Thus I'm puzzled whether there's a better way.

Comment: if my grammar is your biggest problem here, that means you have got the point here.

Comment: http://media.tumblr.com/d236de77a0606b14bfbc151961c6dc39/tumblr_inline_n5sqlr3iYO1raprkq.gif

Comment: sorry for making you sad with highlighting you may read more and can educate yourself and linking the related official documents as well. my bad. it won't happen again, my lazy friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is from an earlier Xcode 6 beta, the correct answer now (Xcode 7/Swift 2) is** https://stackoverflow.com/a/32004398/669586

---

The following is possible:

```
if (theEvent.modifierFlags & NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask).value != 0 {
```

because there is a definition of `&` for `RawOptionSet`

```
func &<T : RawOptionSet>(a: T, b: T) -> T
```

However, note that `RawOptionSet` also implements `LogicValue`, so the following is possible, too:

```
if theEvent.modifierFlags & NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask {
```

Although I consider the first solution to be a bit more clear for the readers

Comment: I actually prefer the last option, accepting this as an answer. Additional question - is there any way to check for if operator is defined for a protocol?

Comment: @mdomans No, you can only check the Swift "headers" or just try to use it... My first idea was to define it and then I found it already defined.

Comment: It seems that value has been made private in Xcode 6 beta 4, so the first method no longer works.

Comment: I'll point future visitors to the new correct answer until it rises above this one: You must use the second form and add `!= nil`.

Comment: This doesn't work as of Xcode 6.1.1. Antoine Quint's answer is correct.

Answer (score 24):

The following works in Xcode7-beta3, Swift 2

In Swift 2, bit field style enums like `NSEventModifierFlags` have been updated to conform to the `OptionSetType` protocol.

If you want to check if an option set contains a specific option, you no longer need to use bitwise `&` and a nil check. You can simply ask the option set if it contains a specific value in the same way that you would check if an array contained a value.

```
if theEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.CommandKeyMask) {
```

Comment: This is the cleaner answer (For Swift 2) – i was using: let value = (event.modifierFlags.rawValue & NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask.rawValue) != 0

Answer (score 20):

Xcode6-Beta6 changed this again I believe, the following will now work:

`if theEvent.modifierFlags & .CommandKeyMask != nil {`